# How to set nested property in output object from Hibernate Projections without 3rd party plugin

Tags: java, hibernate

I have below entities -

```
UserDB{
String name;
Address address;
//getter Setter of name & address
}

User{
String name;
Address address;
//getter Setter of name & address
}

Address{
String line1;
String line2;
String postalCode;
//getter setter of line1,line2,postalCode
}
```

Can we set nested property in hibernate Projections like below? Without using third party plugins

```
public User getUserInfo(Long id) {
Criteria criteria = getCriteria(UserDB.class);
criteria.createAlias("addressDB", "addDbAlias", JoinType.INNER_JOIN);
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("name").as("name"))

        .add(Projections.property("addDbAlias.line1").as("address.line1")) //is this ".as(address.line1)" correct way? If not how to achieve this

            .add(Projections.property("addDbAlias.line2").as("address.line2"))
                .add(Projections.property("addDbAlias.postalCode").as("address.postalCode")));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
```

Above code giving error : Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for address.line1 on User

How to solve this error.. Thanks in Advance!!